# adding login credential for App access on google play console

Tags: google-play

I use only google sign-in in my application, how do I add App access instructions for google to test my application. I am failing to find a way of instructing google on how to log in. I thought of using my own email address but then that will require me to authorize them when they try to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to provide credentials, Just write in the instructions that your app are using Google Sign-in and it will work.